# Why doesn't it work finding index in Array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to find out if a key value is in array .. but it doesn't work..

```java
class Solution {
  public int solution(int key, int[] array1) {
      int answer = 0;
      for(int i=0; i < array1.length; i++) {
          if(array1[i] == key) {
              answer = i;
          }
          else return -1;
      }
      return answer;
  }
}
```

ex )    key : 5 array1 : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        answer : 4

Comment: It doesn't work because you immediately return `-1` if the key isn't at the first position of the array without checking the other positions.

Comment: For things like this, your best bet *by far* is to use the debugger built into your IDE to step through the code statement by statement to see what's going wrong. Using the debugger is not an advanced skill, it's basically the next thing you should learn after "Hello, world". Happy coding! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should return an answer when you find a match, or when you finish the loop without finding a match.

You should **not** return -1 if the first element of the array doesn't match your key. You should check all the other elements of the array first.

```
  public int solution(int key, int[] array1) {
      for(int i=0; i < array1.length; i++) {
          if(array1[i] == key) {
              return i;
          }
      }
      return -1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need index of key as output and which you are getting correctly as index of array start from 0.
Index for key as 5 is 4 which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should put return outside for loop:

```
class Solution {
  public int solution(int key, int[] array1) {
      int answer = -1;
      for(int i=0; i < array1.length; i++) {
          if(array1[i] == key) {
              answer = i;
          }
      }
      return answer;
  }
}
```